# How to call an AsyncTask in an Infinite Loop and update ListView simultaneously?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I've just started learning Android and I'm trying to make a web service call using `AsyncTask` in a Fragment. I want the `AsyncTask` to stop when I stop receiving data. I also want to update a `ListView` in the `onPostExecute()` method of my `AsyncTask`. I have tried the following but I'm unable to get it to work. The `AsyncTask` runs only for the first time and stops. What changes should I make?

**Code in my `Fragment` and its `onCreateView()` method**

```
 JSONObject dataReceiverObject;


 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
int param1, param2;

while (true){
            new MyAsyncTaskClass().execute(param1,param2);

                param1 = param2;
                param2 = param2 + 10;
            if (dataReceiverObject==null)
                break;
        }


return view;
}
```

**Code in my `AsyncTask` class**

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
 try {

                dataReceiverObject = //fetch JSON data by passing 
                //params[0] and params[1]


        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    if (dataReceiverObject != null) {
                try {

                    //code to add data to an ArrayList
                    adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), arraylistObject);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In doInBackground() method call a thread

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
 try {

            dataReceiverObject = //fetch JSON data by passing 
            //params[0] and params[1]

       //after receiving data from web server call new thread and pass the received data as parameter
      updateListView(arraylistObject);
    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and now define method as follows

```
public void updateListView(final String[] arraylistObj){

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
              if(arraylistObj.length>0){
               adapter = new MyListAdapter(getActivity(), arraylistObject);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
             }
          }
       });
     }
```

Comment: Fabulous answer! However, a minor change that was needed was to call runOnUiThread() method using getActivity(). I've edited it. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

execute new AsyncTask from onPostExecute function do it till you get all of your data from web service use indexing to maintain downloaded data.